# Assigning single dataset column to a combox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, combobox

I have a dataset that is returned from a web service. The dataset has multiple columns. Is there an easy way to assign a given column to the combobox without having to iterate through the dataset?

Something on the end of this. I have tried all sorts of properties...

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = suppDataSet.Tables(0)

ComboBox1.DataSource = suppDataSet.Tables(0).Columns(2).tostring

ComboBox1.DataSource = suppDataSet.Tables(0).Columns(2)
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you need to check out the displaymember and valuemember properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LINQ as follows:

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = From dr As DataRow In suppDataSet.Tables(0).Rows 
                       Select CStr(dr(column_index or column_name))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim oList As New ArrayList

For Each oRow As DataRow In suppDataSet.Tables(0).Rows
    oList.Add(oRow.Item(0))
Next

ComboBox1.DataSource = oList
```

Initially copy required column data in one `ArrayList` and assign `ArrayList` to `ComboBox1.DataSource`.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid the for loop. I was loooking for a way to directly assign the column to the combobox.